# Magento2 Rest Api for social login

Tags: magento2, rest-api, social

Create a new api for social login, we send access token to Facebook,
based on the token read the customer details from  Facebook and create a customer account. In response should be a username and password.

Comment: Atleast post some code you've tried and issue you have faced, Magento SE is QA site ,  smh ...

Comment: @shivashankar Have you get any solution for login and create a customer account API for facebook ?